# server program upgrade problems

Tags: server, apt, upgrade, updates

I am running `12.04LTS` and the system tells me that there are packages to be updated.
The next commands are working:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

One or more of the programs/packages that it is updating hangs the system I have to turn it off to have it come back up.

Is there a way to determine which packages need upgrading and can I update ONE package at a time until I determine which one fails and hangs the system?

Or do you guys have another route of diagnosis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check what files will be upgrading with `--simulate` or `-s`.

```
sudo apt-get -s upgrade
```

Once you know what packages will be upgraded and the actions will be performed you can do `sudo apt-get upgrade package` to upgrade just that package.